# How do I create a dictionary-like android app using HashMap for words and their respective meanings?

Tags: android, dictionary, android-edittext, hashmap, textview

I'm trying to create an app that works like a dictionary (using `HashMap`), where a user types in a word (jargon) in the `textEdit` and if that word matches any of the words in `HashMap`, will display my predefined meaning of the word in a `textView` when user hits `enter`.

Here's my `java code`:

```
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Map;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.TextView;


public class MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity 
{   
// read input
EditText searchField = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.searchField);
String word = searchField.getText(); 
// Error: I'm being prompted to convert this to Editable, should I?

//display output;
String meaning = lookup(word);
TextView displayField = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.displayField);
displayField.setText(meaning); 
// I'm getting a multiple syntax error marker at this line


@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    Map<String, String> dictionary = new HashMap<String, String>();
    dictionary.put("Doe", "a deer, a female deer");
    dictionary.put("Ray", "a drop of golden sun");
}
    public String lookup (String input){
        return dictionary.get(input); 
// Error at this line: dictionary cannot be reslolved, multiple eclipse suggestions none of which seem to work
    }
```

and here's my xml file:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
tools:context="com.safelintels.hgsdreamdictionary.MainActivity" >

<EditText
    android:id="@+id/searchField"
    android:textSize="25sp"
    android:layout_width="330dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:ems="10"
    android:hint="Enter word"
    android:textColor="#000000"
    android:lines="1"
    android:imeOptions="actionSearch"
    android:maxLines="1"
    tools:ignore="RtlHardcoded,TextFields,HardcodedText,UnusedAttribute" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/displayField"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignEnd="@+id/searchField"
    android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/searchField"
    android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
    android:layout_alignRight="@+id/searchField"
    android:layout_below="@+id/searchField"
    android:textColor="#000000"
    android:textSize="20sp"
    tools:ignore="HardcodedText,RtlHardcoded,RtlCompat" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Most of the answers given to somewhat similar questions on this site and others have suggested creating a `database`. However, I don't want that approach because I won't be storing so many words, just a few words and meanings.

Thank you for your kind suggestions in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I recommend using the Map class rather than nested if statements because this will work much faster. A Map is indexed, which means that rather than evaluating every if condition until it finds a match, your program will immediately go to the matching entry in the Map. If the input is not found in the map, it will return `null`.

```
Map<String, String> dictionary = new HashMap<String, String>;
dictionary.put("lunch", "the meal you eat in the afternoon");
dictionary.put("dinner", "the meal you eat after lunch");

    public String lookup (String input) {
        return dictionary.get(input);
    }
```

If you are dead set on using if statements, might I recommend using a `switch` instead. It acts the same as having a long list of if / else if statements but it's easier to read. Please note: prior to Java 7 you cannot use Strings in the `switch` block, which means you will have to individual if statements.

```
public String otherLookup(String input) {
    switch (input) {
        case "lunch":
            return "the meal you eat in the middle of the day";
        case "dinner":
            return "the meal you eat after lunch";
        case "other":
            return "all your other strings here; very tedious";
    }
    return "";
}
```

In all cases you will read in the text input like this:

```
//read in user input
EditText inputField = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.yourId);
String inputText = inputField.getText();

//display output; you can put this code inside of an onClick type of method if you want it to be triggered by a button click
String outputText = lookup(inputText);
TextView outputDisplay = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.yourOtherId);
outputDisplay.setText(outputText);
```

EDITED ANSWER:
Add a button to your UI. When the user clicks this button, it will trigger your dictionary lookup. Right now your app is trying to run the word lookup right when the app starts up, before the user can put anything in the EditText field. So put this in your layout.xml where you have the TextView and EditText:

```
<Button android:id="@+id/lookupButton"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Look Up Word"
            android:onClick="lookup"/>
```

Then put this code in as your main Activity. Sorry, I think I misunderstood the context in which you were using this. I believe this should work much better:

```
public class MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity {

    //assign the UI widgets to variables so you can access them later.
    EditText searchField = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.searchField);
    TextView displayField = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.displayField);
    Map<String, String> dictionary = new HashMap<String, String>();

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);


        dictionary.put("Doe", "a deer, a female deer");
        dictionary.put("Ray", "a drop of golden sun");
    }

    //this lookup() method is what gets called when the user clicks the Button.
    //this View parameter refers to the View that the user clicks to trigger the method call; in your case, this is the Button.
    public void lookup(View view) {
        //use .toString() to cast the input to a String that won't be updated whenever the user
        // changes what is in the EditText field; sorry, I overlooked that before
        String word = searchField.getText().toString();

        //this line looks up the value in your dictionary and sticks it in the TextView for the user to see
        displayField.setText(dictionary.get(word));
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for your prompt and detailed response @Chamatake-san, this appears to be what I'm trying to achieve. Will give it a shot and update you. One question though, what's the advantage(s) of implementing this dictionary-like app using a database?

Comment: @user180845 I honestly haven't worked with databases in Android apps yet, but I assume you would only want to use a database if you have a large volume that you need to reference or if you want to have one central dictionary reference that multiple users can hit while using your app. The advantages to using a database would be that if you wanted to change anything in your dictionary reference, you only need to update the database. Without a database, you basically have to push an updated version of your app to all users, which is not a scalable solution.

Comment: I adapted your suggestion to my code and I got all kinds errors, I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong. Please help.

Comment: @user180845 Sorry, I don't think I understood the context in which you were going to implement this originally. I've edited my answer. The revised code should run better, hopefully without errors.

Comment: thanks a million for your kind assistance. I really appreciate it. 

Answer (score 0):

Best to declare the UI varibles as `private`, and then initialize them inside the `onCreate` `method` to avoid a `NullPointerException` `error`:

```
public class MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity {   

Map<String, String> map = new HashMap<String, String>();
private EditText searchField;
private TextView displayField;
String word;

@Override
        protected  void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        searchField = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.searchField);
        displayField = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.displayField);
        Button button = (Button)findViewById(R.id.button);
        button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

            String word = searchField.getText().toString();
            displayField.setText(map.get(word);

        dictionary.put("Doe", "a deer, a female deer");
        dictionary.put("Ray", "a drop of golden sun");
    }
```